# Application of forcing to first-order properties of rings

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, noetherian, forcing

I'm not very well acquainted with forcing, just with the basic ideas; but I thought of the following proof, and since I'm definitely not comfortable with forcing I don't know if it's right, so my question is :

> Is the following proof valid ? If not, can a bit of work make it valid, or is there an essential mistake ?

The question is the following : suppose you have a property $P$ that can be expressed in the first order language of rings; and assume that ZFC proves "if a ring $R$ satisfies $P$ and is countable, then $R$ is noetherian".

I want to prove that then ZFC proves "if a ring $R$ satisfies $P$, then $R$ is noetherian".

Let $V$ be a model of ZFC, by Löwenheim-Skolem one may assume that $V$ is countable (we may assume $V$ exists because we may assume ZFC is consistent). Let $R$ be a $V$-ring (I can clarify what this means but I think it's clear) that satisfies $P$ and $S$ a set of ideals of $R$.

Now consider a forcing extension $V[G]$ that sees $R$ as countable (this can be done because $V$ is countable, and we can use the classical collapsing forcing).

In this extension $R$ still satisfies $P$ (this is where I'm no comfortable : though if I recall correctly, first order assertions about $R$ are preserved under extensions), and is countable. Hence, it is noetherian, and hence $S$ (which is still a set of ideals of $R$) has a maximal element $I$. But $I\in S$ so $I\in V$ because $V$ is a transitive submodel of $V[G]$. Moreover, "$I$ is maximal in $S$" is absolute (that seems clear but I'd also like to be sure about this) so $V$ sees that $S$ has a maximal element;
To conclude, $V$ sees $R$ as noetherian.

This yields that "$R$ has $P$ $\implies$ $R$ is noetherian" is provable as well.

Is that correct ?

Comment: @DanielSchepler : and what do you do afterwards ? I lean, how do you get the noetherianity of $R$ from that of this elementarily equivalent subring ?

Comment: Looks good to me... BTW in Forcing we do not actually assume that there is a model for all of  ZFC. And even the assumption that some (V,E) is a model for ZFC does not imply that E can be a well-founded relation on V, so it does not imply that ZFC has a transitive  model.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : thank you ! Indeed we definitely don't need all of ZFC, but why not here ? For the second point, yes I know that $V$ need not be transitive, but it is nonetheless a transitive *submodel* of $V[G]$, isn't it ?

Comment: The V in your Q $is$ transitive. Forcing only works on countable transitive models. We can say in the meta-theory that if you give  me a finite list of axioms of ZFC then I can prove in ZFC that there is a c.t.m. V for them. But it is a common  convenience to  speak of V as if it satisfies all of ZFC.  Perhaps this is old news to you....BTW  I was wondering if you have a non-trivial  example of the P of your Q

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : oh right, no when writing the question I did not think of that but now that you mention it, I do remember ! I might have, I actually thoight about this because of a specific $P$ that a friend said he had proved it satisfied the hypotheses of my Q. If he confirms the proof I'll mention the property

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : it turns out that my friend had made a mistake in his proof, so I don't actually have an example of such a $P$...

Comment: @DanielWainfleet "Forcing only works on countable transitive models." That's not true. We can develop forcing over arbitrary countable models of set theory along the usual lines with a bit more care, and over arbitrary models via the Boolean valued approach (this is how Jech presents forcing).

Comment: The key to developing forcing over arbitrary countable models of set theory without any substantial changes (e.g. without switching to Boolean-valued models) is the realization that all the actual applications of well-foundedness occur to justify various recursions, but these recursions are all *internal* and so they go through with minor cosmetic changes in any model of regularity. The one twist is the proof that $M[G]$ satisfies regularity: in the transitive case this is done via cheating ("$M[G]$ is a set with the usual $\in$-relation, so is well-founded since $V$ is"). (cont'd)

Comment: In the arbitrary-countable-model case, we need to argue instead that from a name for a failure of regularity in $M[G]$ we can produce a failure of regularity in $M$. But this isn't hard: we first prove the usual forcing lemmas for the syntactic version of forcing (what Kunen calls $\Vdash^*$ if I recall correctly) by internal recursion as stated above, and then just show that if $\mu$ is a name which is forced by some condition $p$ to be a set of ordinals with no minimum, then the set of "$p$-possible elements" of $\mu$ has no minimum (and this set is in $M$ by definability of $\Vdash^*$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber  . I'm rusty on this.In the near future I think I'll be more of a spectator.